# Temperature reached in x minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with some temperature measurements and some timestamps. In this I will find out if there is a continuous period of 10 minutes where the temperature is 80 degrees or above.

First some testdata:

```
declare @TestTable Table
(
  Temperature int,
   TimeStamp DateTime2
)

insert into  @TestTable  values
(84, '2018-01-11 13:46:17.2933333'),
(82, '2018-01-11 13:46:47.2900000'),
(83, '2018-01-11 13:47:17.4300000'),
(44, '2018-01-11 13:47:47.4266667'),
(27, '2018-01-11 13:48:17.4300000'),
(21, '2018-01-11 13:48:47.4300000'),
(18, '2018-01-11 13:49:17.4300000'),
(17, '2018-01-11 13:49:47.4333333'),
(16, '2018-01-11 13:50:17.4433333'),
(16, '2018-01-11 13:50:47.4800000'),
(18, '2018-01-11 13:51:17.4833333'),
(19, '2018-01-11 13:51:47.5000000'),
(21, '2018-01-11 13:52:17.5333333'),
(24, '2018-01-11 13:52:47.5500000'),
(28, '2018-01-11 13:53:17.5500000'),
(30, '2018-01-11 13:53:47.5800000'),
(28, '2018-01-11 13:54:17.6200000'),
(31, '2018-01-11 13:54:47.6133333'),
(33, '2018-01-11 13:55:17.6133333'),
(34, '2018-01-11 13:55:47.6166667'),
(35, '2018-01-11 13:56:17.6333333'),
(35, '2018-01-11 13:56:47.6366667'),
(36, '2018-01-11 13:57:17.6500000'),
(37, '2018-01-11 13:57:47.6500000'),
(25, '2018-01-11 13:58:17.6533333'),
(16, '2018-01-11 13:58:47.6533333'),
(13, '2018-01-11 13:59:17.6566667'),
(12, '2018-01-11 13:59:47.6533333'),
(11, '2018-01-11 14:00:17.6533333'),
(11, '2018-01-11 14:00:47.6700000'),
(11, '2018-01-11 14:01:17.6833333'),
(11, '2018-01-11 14:01:47.6900000'),
(13, '2018-01-11 14:02:17.6900000'),
(14, '2018-01-11 14:02:47.7066667'),
(15, '2018-01-11 14:03:17.7066667'),
(16, '2018-01-11 14:03:47.7233333'),
(17, '2018-01-11 14:04:17.7233333'),
(18, '2018-01-11 14:04:47.7400000'),
(19, '2018-01-11 14:05:17.7566667'),
(20, '2018-01-11 14:05:47.7733333'),
(20, '2018-01-11 14:06:17.7733333'),
(20, '2018-01-11 14:06:47.8066667'),
(21, '2018-01-11 14:07:17.8066667'),
(22, '2018-01-11 14:07:47.8233333'),
(22, '2018-01-11 14:08:17.8233333')
```

I've tried CROSS APPLY and I've tried Exists:

**CROSS APPLY**

```
select T.TimeStamp, t.Temperature from  @TestTable T
CROSS APPLY 
(
      select * from Temperatures T2 
        where 
          T.TimeStamp = T2.TimeStamp AND
          T2.Temperature >= 80 AND
          T2.TimeStamp >= T.TimeStamp 
          AND T2.TimeStamp < dateadd(minute, 10, t.TimeStamp)
) A
```

**Exists:**

```
select T.TimeStamp, t.Temperature from  @TestTable T
where exists (select  1 from @TestTable T2 
                    where T2.Temperature >= 80 AND
                    T2.TimeStamp >= T.TimeStamp and
                    T2.TimeStamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, T.TimeStamp)
                    )
```

Both gives me the wrong answer. Which is an empty table.

[image]

Comment: does your sample data has any records that has `continuous period of 10 minutes where the temperature is 80 degrees or above.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will gives you the sets of data where the continuous temperature is higher than 80

```
; with cte as
(
    select  rn = row_number() over (order by TimeStamp),    
        *, flag = case when Temperature >= 80 then 1 else 0 end
    from    @TestTable
)
,
cte2 as
(
    select  *, grp  = rn - rank() over (partition by flag order by TimeStamp)
    from    cte
)
select  grp, min(TimeStamp), max(TimeStamp)
from    cte2
where   flag    = 1
group by grp
```

Comment: To find the continuous 10 minutes where the temperature is 80 degrees or above... you need to add the having clause in above query "having DATEDIFF(Minute, min(TimeStamp), max(TimeStamp))>10"

Answer (score 1):

This query will return continuos periods of 10 minute

```
select
    a.TimeStamp, dateadd(mi, 10, a.TimeStamp)
from
    @TestTable a
    join @TestTable b on b.TimeStamp between a.TimeStamp and dateadd(mi, 10, a.TimeStamp)
group by a.TimeStamp
having min(b.Temperature)>=80
```

Answer (score 1):

10 period time consideration is confusing minds
What I expect is at least for 10 minutes the temperature does not drop under defined limits
So "no rows" result is correct

I had prepared following query and changed criteria to test the SELECT statement

```
declare @interval int = 3
declare @templimit int = 20

;with cte as (
    select
        t1.Temperature Temperature1,
        t1.timestamp timestamp1,
        t2.Temperature Temperature2,
        t2.timestamp timestamp2,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.timestamp order by t2.timestamp desc) as rn,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t2.timestamp order by t1.timestamp) as rn2
    from TestTable t1
    inner join TestTable t2 on t2.timestamp >= dateadd(mi,@interval,t1.timestamp)
    where
        t1.Temperature >= @templimit and
        t2.Temperature >= @templimit and
        t1.timestamp <> t2.timestamp
        and not exists (
            select * from TestTable t3 
            where 
                t3.timestamp between t1.timestamp and t2.timestamp 
                and t3.Temperature < @templimit
        )
)
select
    timestamp1,
    Temperature1,
    timestamp2,
    Temperature2
from cte 
where rn = 1 and rn2 = 1
order by timestamp1
```

I checked that above returns more precise values when milliseconds are considered

Comment: I dont understand your solution, because it gives med the same result at my quries

Comment: I'm comparing results with @Squirrel's solution by adding the HAVING clause as "having DATEDIFF(mi, min(TimeStamp), max(TimeStamp)) >= @interval" just as Mittal suggested